# Connecting with interviewer on LinkedIn post interview

Tags: linkedin, networking

I just interviewed with a company for a systems / business analyst position through a recruiting agency. Through my recruiter, I found out I was **not chosen** for the position, after only a few candidates were left in the final rounds.

I felt I really connected with my interviewers and really liked the company, both in terms of cultural fit, and position suitability.Through our conversation, I discovered we shared a similar background and many similar interests.

The interviewers seemed to really take interest in me as a strong candidate - answering my questions fully and selling me the benefits of working for the company, such as the flat hierarchy and small team based culture. I found these to be very appealing.

I am thinking of connecting with interviewers on LinkedIn as I would be interested in maintaining a professional connection with them, and in case o future employment opportunities.

**Is there an etiquette in connecting with interviewers on LinkedIn for an interview that was unsuccessful?**

Comment: Don't be surprised if your LinkedIn request is ignored.

Comment: Does the company itself have a profile page on LinkedIn? If so, you could follow that page as a way of indicating your continuing interest, and to watch for any future announcements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there an etiquette in connecting with interviewers on LinkedIn for
>   an interview that was unsuccessful?

There is no special etiquette, and it doesn't matter if the interview was successful or unsuccessful. It's not really anything to worry about.

Invite a connection to the interviewers. If they took an interest in you through your similar background and shared interests, and you clearly liked them, then they may accept the invitation.

Even if they did like you, they may still choose to ignore or reject your invitation. If that happens, don't take it personally. Many folks are very careful about their personal LinkedIn network.

However, it's worth a shot. You have nothing to lose here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a recruiter who is working for a company and used to work as an external agent /consultant. I think it is great if you had a good interview for you to connect and also follow the company page. I am more likely to remember you and we also run searches on people who actually follow our company.

If there was a real interest then in most cases I would email the person and ask them to keep in touch or if via an agent, then ask them to.