# Is it appropriate to connect to a company CEO on LinkedIn after interview?

Tags: hiring, linkedin, networking

Approximately one year ago, I had a job interview with the CEO and the R&D manager of a company which was looking for new employees. Unfortunately, even if the interviews and selection processes were successful for me, at the end I was not hired.
Would it be okay now to add them on my LinkedIn network (eventually, adding a dedicated connection request message), mainly to let them stay up-to-date with my career progresses and, in case, for me to not miss future hirings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting with interviewer on LinkedIn post interview](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52341/connecting-with-interviewer-on-linkedin-post-interview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be okay now to add them on my LinkedIn network (eventually,
> adding a dedicated connection request message), mainly to let them
> stay up-to-date with my career progresses and, in case, for me to not
> miss future hirings?

There is very little to no harm in sending an invite over.

People have different requirements and expectations before accepting, but as this isn't out of the blue as you've met, it for sure wouldn't be rude to send an invitation over. But also be prepared to not get accepted, it greatly varies from person to person.

Comment: And if you do send an invite, type something personal.  Nothing gets ignored quicker than "I'd like to add you to my LinkedIn network".

Answer (score 3):

It's not inappropriate but probably won't have much effect. If I'm hiring people, I don't go looking though my LinkedIn connections for people I previously interviewed, I just go to my recruiters (internal or external as appropriate).

Comment: But if he adds them, he will be notified of their posts which could be a job vacancy.

Comment: @FooTheBar 1) in general, it's not the CEO who posts the "we're hiring" posts (except in very small companies), maybe more value for the R&D Manager 2) that can be done be following them. If you care about the "we're hiring" posts, find the recruiters instead.

Comment: He was interviewed by the CEO so it looks like a rather small company